# How can I access a webcam on the host from inside a WSL2 environment? cap_v4l.cpp:1119 tryIoctl VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): select() timeout

Tags: python, opencv, windows-subsystem-for-linux, video-capture, wsl-2

I'm running the following version of WSL

```
5.15.90.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2+
```

with Python 3 and OpenCV Version 4.8.0

This is the code which should open a window with the video stream captured by a Logitech C910 connected via USB

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:0821 Logitech, Inc. HD Webcam C910
```

The device is found

```bash
~/01_PROJECTS/spiderrobot/source$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:0821 Logitech, Inc. HD Webcam C910
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

It throws this error after some time

```
[ WARN:0@10.193] global cap_v4l.cpp:1119 tryIoctl VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): select() timeout.
Failed to read frame from video capture.
```

```py
import cv2

# Set the video codec, output file name, and frame rate
codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
output_file = 'output.avi'
frame_rate = 30.0

# Set up the video capture object
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Check if camera opened successfully
if not video_capture.isOpened():
    print("Failed to open video capture.")
    exit(1)

# Get the video frame width and height from the capture object
frame_width = int(video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
frame_height = int(video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

# Check if resolution retrieval was successful
if frame_width == 0 or frame_height == 0:
    print("Failed to retrieve frame resolution.")
    video_capture.release()
    exit(1)

# Create a VideoWriter object to save the recorded video
video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(
    output_file, codec, frame_rate, (frame_width, frame_height))

# Check if VideoWriter was successfully opened
if not video_writer.isOpened():
    print("Failed to open VideoWriter.")
    video_capture.release()
    exit(1)

while True:
    # Capture the video frame by frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    # Break the loop if no frame is captured
    if not ret:
        print("Failed to read frame from video capture.")
        break

    # Display the captured frame
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    # Write the frame to the video file
    if not video_writer.write(frame):
        print("Failed to write frame to video file.")
        break

    # Break the loop if the 'q' key is pressed
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

# Release the video capture and writer objects
video_capture.release()
video_writer.release()

# Close all OpenCV windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I compiled the WSL kernel with the necessary drivers (I used my current WSL version when building the kernel)

[Build WSL2 kernel with usb camera support](https://agiledevart.github.io/wsl2_usb_camera.txt)

this command works flawlessly opening a guvcview window where I can see the camera stream. The camera LEDs turn on so it looks like the Python 3 code can connect to the camera. After the error, the cameras LEDs turn off.

Can anyone help me resolve this error please?

Comment: debug this with guvcview or similar program. still an issue? I doubt this is an opencv issue. it's an issue of V4L2 not getting access to the host's device -- the traceback is a consequence of not being able to open the video device. `if not ret: break` and also `assert vid.isOpened()`

Comment: how do I debug the code with guvcview?

Comment: wait, so you're saying guvcview from inside of the container _works_? how about ffmpeg reading from v4l2? https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Webcam#Linux you could try setting some properties on the VideoCapture object, like width and height and fourcc: https://forum.opencv.org/t/videoio-v4l2-dev-video0-select-timeout/8822/5 always google for each error/warning message and see where that takes you

Comment: this all looks to me like the v4l2/uvc passthrough is ***incomplete*** and doesn't support some advertised modes (opencv expects those). you should file a bug with WSL2. and never skip the error checking. your code lacks some error checking.

Comment: Yes, guvcview works in the container showing the video stream of my camera. I filed a bug using the MS Feedback Hub. ffmpeg reading from v2l returns this UVC Camera (046d:0821) (usb-vhci_hcd.0-1):
        /dev/video0
        /dev/video1
        /dev/media0 the modified python code with error handling https://gist.github.com/chukZ/53072b10ef0c13c0dbeb681b65e36e33

Comment: setting the VideoCapture's CAP_PROP_FOURCC to MJPG seems to have worked for others (see above link).

Comment: Unfortunately not, this error is thrown when setting this parameter Corrupt JPEG data: 2 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd1. I'll try it on a Ubuntu native machine now

Comment: The code provided above runs perfectly fine on a native Ubuntu machine so I'm happy now